# springboot app shutdown without any error after map reduce task finished

Tags: java, hadoop, spring-boot, pom.xml

i'm building portfolio up by springboot + hadoop.
as exactly same as title, spring boot app closed without any single error message after finished map reduce.
i suffered this kind of error before when i programmed jsoup Crawler.
However, i could fix it by try-catch.
i tried that this time and i couldn't solve it.

here is a computer and program spec.
- macbook pro.(high sieera.
- hadoop version 2.7.3
- springboot version 2.0.0
- spring-data-hadoop-boot 2.5.0

this is console log.

```
] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-05-08 15:58:31.701  INFO 59820 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 15:58:31.702  INFO 59820 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 15:58:31.702  INFO 59820 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 15:58:31.702  INFO 59820 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 15:58:31.969  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-05-08 15:58:32.444  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-05-08 15:58:32.482  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-08 15:58:32.496  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-05-08 15:58:32.582  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2018-05-08 15:58:32.584  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-08 15:58:32.629  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-05-08 15:58:32.714  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2018-05-08 15:58:33.131  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-08 15:58:33.448  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-05-08 15:58:34.226  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2acb939f: startup date [Tue May 08 15:58:29 KST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-08 15:58:34.276  WARN 59820 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-05-08 15:58:34.333  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dc/list],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.logan.controller.DcController.list(com.logan.domain.Dc_base,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
2018-05-08 15:58:34.334  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dc/view],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.logan.controller.DcController.view(java.lang.Long,com.logan.domain.Dc_base,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 15:58:34.335  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dc/crawl],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.logan.controller.DcController.crawl() throws java.io.IOException
2018-05-08 15:58:34.335  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dc/hadoop],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.logan.controller.DcController.hadoop() throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-08 15:58:34.342  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-08 15:58:34.344  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-08 15:58:34.422  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 15:58:34.422  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 15:58:34.516  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 15:58:35.347  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-05-08 15:58:35.410  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.h.c.a.c.SpringHadoopConfiguration  : Building configuration for bean 'hadoopConfiguration'
2018-05-08 15:58:35.667  WARN 59820 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-05-08 15:58:35.880  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.hadoop.fs.TrashPolicyDefault  : Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
2018-05-08 15:58:35.968  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-08 15:58:35.969  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-05-08 15:58:35.977  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-05-08 15:58:35.983  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-05-08 15:58:36.046  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-05-08 15:58:36.064  INFO 59820 --- [  restartedMain] com.logan.Portfolio1Application          : Started Portfolio1Application in 7.61 seconds (JVM running for 8.502)
2018-05-08 15:58:45.737  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-05-08 15:58:45.737  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-05-08 15:58:45.755  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 18 ms
2018-05-08 15:58:46.544  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.conf.Configuration.deprecation     : session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2018-05-08 15:58:46.545  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics   : Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2018-05-08 15:58:46.680  WARN 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader      : Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2018-05-08 15:58:46.692  WARN 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader      : No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2018-05-08 15:58:46.706  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.m.lib.input.FileInputFormat        : Total input paths to process : 1
2018-05-08 15:58:46.835  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter   : number of splits:1
2018-05-08 15:58:46.935  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter   : Submitting tokens for job: job_local1276007486_0001
2018-05-08 15:58:47.082  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          : The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2018-05-08 15:58:47.083  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          : Running job: job_local1276007486_0001
2018-05-08 15:58:47.085  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : OutputCommitter set in config null
2018-05-08 15:58:47.089  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] o.a.h.m.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter   : File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2018-05-08 15:58:47.091  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2018-05-08 15:58:47.128  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Waiting for map tasks
2018-05-08 15:58:47.129  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Starting task: attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0
2018-05-08 15:58:47.146  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] o.a.h.m.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter   : File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2018-05-08 15:58:47.150  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] o.a.h.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree   : ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2018-05-08 15:58:47.151  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            :  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
2018-05-08 15:58:47.155  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Logan/dc_in/dc_base.csv:0+2715710
2018-05-08 15:58:47.210  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2018-05-08 15:58:47.210  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2018-05-08 15:58:47.210  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : soft limit at 83886080
2018-05-08 15:58:47.210  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2018-05-08 15:58:47.210  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2018-05-08 15:58:47.213  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2018-05-08 15:58:47.441  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : 
2018-05-08 15:58:47.443  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : Starting flush of map output
2018-05-08 15:58:47.443  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : Spilling map output
2018-05-08 15:58:47.443  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : bufstart = 0; bufend = 3249391; bufvoid = 104857600
2018-05-08 15:58:47.443  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 25677028(102708112); length = 537369/6553600
2018-05-08 15:58:48.089  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          : Job job_local1276007486_0001 running in uber mode : false
2018-05-08 15:58:48.091  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          :  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-05-08 15:58:48.143  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask         : Finished spill 0
2018-05-08 15:58:48.148  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            : Task:attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2018-05-08 15:58:48.160  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : map
2018-05-08 15:58:48.161  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            : Task 'attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.161  INFO 59820 --- [ask Executor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Finishing task: attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0
2018-05-08 15:58:48.161  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : map task executor complete.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.162  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Waiting for reduce tasks
2018-05-08 15:58:48.163  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Starting task: attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0
2018-05-08 15:58:48.169  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter   : File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2018-05-08 15:58:48.170  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree   : ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.170  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            :  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
2018-05-08 15:58:48.172  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask      : Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@2c0f65dc
2018-05-08 15:58:48.180  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : MergerManager: memoryLimit=1336252800, maxSingleShuffleLimit=334063200, mergeThreshold=881926912, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2018-05-08 15:58:48.182  INFO 59820 --- [mpletion Events] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.EventFetcher         : attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2018-05-08 15:58:48.215  INFO 59820 --- [ localfetcher#1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.LocalFetcher         : localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 2709391 len: 2709395 to MEMORY
2018-05-08 15:58:48.219  INFO 59820 --- [ localfetcher#1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput    : Read 2709391 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1276007486_0001_m_000000_0
2018-05-08 15:58:48.223  INFO 59820 --- [ localfetcher#1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 2709391, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->2709391
2018-05-08 15:58:48.225  INFO 59820 --- [mpletion Events] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.EventFetcher         : EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
2018-05-08 15:58:48.225  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : 1 / 1 copied.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.226  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : finalMerge called with 1 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
2018-05-08 15:58:48.231  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger          : Merging 1 sorted segments
2018-05-08 15:58:48.232  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger          : Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 2709387 bytes
2018-05-08 15:58:48.304  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : Merged 1 segments, 2709391 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2018-05-08 15:58:48.304  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : Merging 1 files, 2709395 bytes from disk
2018-05-08 15:58:48.305  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl     : Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2018-05-08 15:58:48.305  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger          : Merging 1 sorted segments
2018-05-08 15:58:48.306  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger          : Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 2709387 bytes
2018-05-08 15:58:48.307  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : 1 / 1 copied.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.329  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.conf.Configuration.deprecation     : mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2018-05-08 15:58:48.547  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            : Task:attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2018-05-08 15:58:48.550  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : 1 / 1 copied.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.550  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            : Task attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2018-05-08 15:58:48.557  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.a.h.m.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter   : Saved output of task 'attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Logan/dc_in/out/_temporary/0/task_local1276007486_0001_r_000000
2018-05-08 15:58:48.558  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : reduce > reduce
2018-05-08 15:58:48.558  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task            : Task 'attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0' done.
2018-05-08 15:58:48.558  INFO 59820 --- [pool-7-thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : Finishing task: attempt_local1276007486_0001_r_000000_0
2018-05-08 15:58:48.559  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-33] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  : reduce task executor complete.
2018-05-08 15:58:49.098  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          :  map 100% reduce 100%
2018-05-08 15:58:49.099  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          : Job job_local1276007486_0001 completed successfully
2018-05-08 15:58:49.108  INFO 59820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          : Counters: 35
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=5419178
        FILE: Number of bytes written=8693317
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=5431420
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=2341190
        HDFS: Number of read operations=15
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=6
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=19172
        Map output records=134343
        Map output bytes=3249391
        Map output materialized bytes=2709395
        Input split bytes=115
        Combine input records=134343
        Combine output records=92172
        Reduce input groups=92172
        Reduce shuffle bytes=2709395
        Reduce input records=92172
        Reduce output records=92172
        Spilled Records=184344
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1330642944
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=2715710
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=2341190
2018-05-08 15:58:49.109  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2acb939f: startup date [Tue May 08 15:58:29 KST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-08 15:58:49.112  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-05-08 15:58:49.217  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-08 15:58:49.218  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-05-08 15:58:49.219  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-08 15:58:49.222  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-05-08 15:58:49.229  INFO 59820 --- [      Thread-12] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.logan</groupId>
    <artifactId>portfolio-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>portfolio-1</name>
    <description>JSOUP + SPRINGBOOT + JPA + DB + HADOOP + R + HIVE + THYMELEAF</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring hadoop 2.5 -->
        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.2.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.1.4</version> -->
        </dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: How do you launch your application? What is your IDE (e.g. Spring STS, Intellij)? If you are doing it via command prompt please let me know what command are you using at start-up

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. i've using eclipse neon and install sts plugin init.
launch app on DashBoard. !
i put hadoop method in controller.
hadoop worked very well. when i enter localhost:8080/dc/hadoop.
then bootapp shutdown automatically when process finished it..;;